# Powershell operaciones mátemáticas con campos de un fichreo csv

Tags: csv, matrices, powershell

Tengo un fichero csv con esta cabecera y estos campos:

```
Path,CurrentFileCount,CurrentFileSize,FileCount,DirectoryCount,DirectorySize,DirectorySizeOnDisk
\\srvcd01\c$\fs_calculo\022ca\022cf\proyectos\160272,1,1439,159,32,35870243,35993600
```

Y quiero dividir el campo DirectorySizeOnDisk entre 1073741824 para tenerlo en GB e incluirlo en este csv u otro

¿Cómo puedo hacer?

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a SOes y te aliento a que leas [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que estas y otras preguntas futuras sean mejor recibidas por la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

Para ello tienes que usar la función [Import-Csv](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6).

- **Si el archivo tiene solo una entrada:**

Primero hay que importar los datos del archivo (detallar la ruta):

```
$datos = Import-Csv .\Desktop\stack.csv
```

Luego, reemplazamos el valor en la variable, accediendo a la propiedad por el nombre:

```
$datos.DirectorySizeOnDisk = $datos.DirectorySizeOnDisk / 1073741824
```

Y por último guardamos los datos en memoria dentro del archivo .csv anterior:

```
$datos | Export-Csv .\Desktop\stack.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Y listo. Todo lo anterior en bloque sería lo siguiente:

```
$datos = Import-Csv .\Desktop\stack.csv
$datos.DirectorySizeOnDisk = $datos.DirectorySizeOnDisk / 1073741824
$datos | Export-Csv .\Desktop\stack.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

- **Si el archivo tiene más entradas:**

El bloque sería el siguiente:

```
($datos = Import-Csv .\Desktop\stack.csv) | ForEach {
    $_.DirectorySizeOnDisk = $_.DirectorySizeOnDisk / 1073741824
}
$datos | Export-Csv .\Desktop\stack.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Espero haber respondido tu pregunta.